# why column name didn't catch the placeholder in MS SQL using Case for date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i was trying to get the placeholder in their respected columns but getting NULL only. help me out where i have done wrong.

```
select [Created Date],
Case 
when [Created Date] BETWEEN '16/07/2016' AND '15/07/2017' then '2073/74' 
when [Created Date] BETWEEN '16/07/2017' AND '15/07/2018' then '2073/74' 
when [Created Date] BETWEEN '16/07/2018' AND '15/07/2019' then '2074/75' 
end as Fiscal_Year ,
[Vendor Name]
from dbo.Vendor
```

Result :

```
Created Date        Fiscal_Year Vendor Name
30/11/2017 08:12 PM   NULL      Al Safa Food Trading
30/11/2017 08:13 PM   NULL      Star Fresh Foods FZC
30/11/2017 08:43 PM   NULL      Green Foods Import - Export
30/11/2017 08:47 PM   NULL      SIDCO Foods Trading
30/11/2017 08:48 PM   NULL      Gulf Foods Trading
30/11/2017 08:54 PM   NULL      Lebanon Crescent Foods Impex
```

Comment: Can you post the DDL of your Table `dbo.Vendor` please?

Comment: How is this a fiscal year: `2073/74`

Comment: Convert `[Created Date]` to date when checking with `BETWEEN` clause

Comment: Try adding your dates in ISO format, e.g. 16/07/2016 would become 20160716.  This will rule out any regional date format issues.  I would also add a placeholder for anything that drops through your CASE statement, as this is where the NULLs are coming from.  So you could add an ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), [Created Date]) statement, to display the actual date for anything that fails to be assigned to a category?

Comment: @Valerica What I was thinking, but  really the OP should be storing date & times and (unsurprisingly) a `datetime`. Storing them as a varchar causes a lot of problems.

Comment: @Tanner country's  system for fiscal year :D 
 
i solved it !! thanks guys 


 set dateformat dmy
  select [Created Date],
  Case   
  when CAST([Created Date] AS datetime) BETWEEN CAST('16/07/2017' as datetime) AND CAST('15/07/2018' AS date) then '2074/75' 
 end as Fiscal_Year ,
  [Vendor Name]
  from dbo.Vendor

Comment: @SudipBala I suggest you have a read of my answer, and reconsider your data type choices.

Comment: thanks @Larnu . i got that :)

Comment: @Larnu i used the other type because of out local date system. we have 32 days in our month

Comment: If you have 32 days, then if you ever have a date like `32/12/2017` then the sql `CONVERT(date, [Created Date])` is going to fail, there aren't 32 days in December. What would, for example, `32/12/2017` represent?

Comment: that is just for reference  .  we use a different date time called 'Bikram Sambat'.  @Larnu

Comment: If you need to represent dates a different way, then still store them as dates. Then, use a computed column or a date table to display them as you require (such as using "Birkam Sambat"). As you can see from my post, storing dates as something that isn't a date but trying to treat them as one yields very "wrong" results, or can cause huge efficiency problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting an answer, as a comment isn't going to really suffice to explain this.

From the comments, it is clear the OP is using a `varchar` (or similar) to store a date & time. This is **extremely** bad practice. There are a lot of implications on why this is a problem.

Let's, as an example, use what the OP was trying to do here:

```
Case when [Created Date] BETWEEN '16/07/2017' AND '15/07/2018' then '2073/74' END
```

Here, `[Created Date]` has the `varchar` value of `'30/11/2017 08:12 PM'`. Now, we all know that the **date** 30 November 2017 is between 16 July 2017 and 15 July 2018, however, is the `varchar`? The answer is **NO**. The string starts with the character `3`. The highest starting character of the two "dates" in the `CASE` is 1. 3 is greater than 1, so `'30/11/2017 08:12 PM'` is **NOT** between '16/07/2017' and '15/07/2018'.

Now, there are other implications. Let's say we have an Index on `[Created Date]` and we want to do a "simple query" for where the date is in March 2017. We *would think* that the answer would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE [Created Date] >= '20170301'
  AND [Created Date] < '20170401';
```

This won't return the results we expect (I actually expect it to return none), as `'20170301'` would be treated as a string, not a date. So, why not use `convert`?

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONVERT(datetime2(0),[Created Date]) >= '20170301'
  AND CONVERT(datetime2(0),[Created Date]) < '20170401';
```

Well, that'll work, but the `INDEX` is now **completely useless**. The ordering of a `date` is completely different to a `varchar`. Indexes work by sorting the data in that index, so that data can be easily found.

Take the following values and "sort" them:

```
29/11/2016 08:13 AM
30/10/2017 08:13 PM
19/12/2018 08:13 AM
```

What answer did you get? Well, if you sorted them as dates then you got:

```
29/11/2016 08:13 AM
30/10/2017 08:13 PM
19/12/2018 08:13 AM
```

However, the OP isn't storing dates, they're storing a `varchar`. Thus, the correct answer is:

```
19/12/2018 08:13 AM
29/11/2017 08:13 AM
30/10/2016 08:13 PM
```

That's "right", 19 December 2018 is BEFORE the dates from 2017 and 2016? And, again 29 November 2017 is before 30 October 2016.

Do you see the problem here? Don't store your data as the WRONG data type. **Ever**. Store dates as Dates, Numbers, as numbers, strings as strings. There is no excuse to do otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select [Created Date],
Case 
when cast([Created Date] as Date) BETWEEN cast('16/07/2016' as date) AND '15/07/2017' then '2073/74' 
when cast([Created Date] as Date) BETWEEN cast('16/07/2017'as date) AND '15/07/2018' then '2073/74' 
when cast([Created Date] as Date) BETWEEN cast('16/07/2018'as date) AND '15/07/2019' then '2074/75' 
end as Fiscal_Year ,
[Vendor Name]
from dbo.Vendor
```

Comment: I really recommend against this. The problem isn't the query, it's the data, which i've taken to time to explain in my "answer" below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select [Created Date],
Case 
when [Created Date] BETWEEN '2016-07-16' AND '2017-07-15' then '2073/74' 
when [Created Date] BETWEEN '2017-07-16' AND '2018-07-15' then '2073/74' 
when [Created Date] BETWEEN '2018-07-16' AND '2019-07-15' then '2074/75' 
end as Fiscal_Year ,
[Vendor Name]
from dbo.Vendor
```